# Find index in list of custom objects

Tags: c#

I have a list: `List<myObject> myList`. It currently holds 3 myObjects. Given an int, I need to know how to find the index of any one of those objects so that I can use it elsewhere. I have tried using lambda statements but for some reason they absolutely do not want to work. I'm actually unsure if they're appropriate for this scenario. I have tried using myList's IndexOf, but I can't seem to get that to work, probably because I'm using custom objects.

If anybody can tell me how to accomplish this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
var myobject = myList.ToArray()[myInt];
```

or just

```
var myobject = myList[myInt];
```

Comment: Why `ToArray`? It is redundant. `myList[myInt]` will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply this

```
var myobject = myList[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can give us some code that would help.

Without any more info, here is something you can try.

```
int indexFound = Array.IndexOf<myObject>(myList.ToArray(), objectToLocateIdexOf);
```